# Using a typedef to create a reference to an array

Tags: c++, for-loop, typedef

I am being asked to make the types of the loop control variables known via a typedef statement. The problem I am having is that I don't know how, or even if it is possible, to make a typedef to a reference to an array of 4 elements.

```
/*
Write a program to print the elements of ia. It should
use a range for to manage the iteration.
*/

int main()
{

int ia[3][4] = {
                {4,3,2,1},
                {1,2,3,4},
                {3,1,4,2}
               };

for (int (&p)[4] : ia)     // This is the line I am talking about
    for(int z : p)
        cout << z;

return 0;
}
```

I am still very new to programming, and I cannot seem to find an answer to this question. Any advice/help regarding the usage of typedef you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::array` to make your life easier?

Comment: Can't you just use `auto&`?

Comment: It says not to use auto

Comment: @ShadowxEnd2 _It says ..._ Huh??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ c++ primer 5th edition chapter 3 exercise 3.43 page 130

Comment: @ShadowxEnd2 Phew! i thought you were talking about dark, evil forces or so. May be it's reasonable to add such kind of restrictions and requirements to your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using at least C++11, which is implied by the range-for statement, you can turn to "using" instead of "typedef". It serves the same uses and more, and it has a less confusing syntax:

```
// Equivalent declarations
typedef int (&arrayRef)[4];
using arrayRef = int (&)[4];
// Usage
for (arrayRef p : ia) { ... }
```

Furthermore, with using you can template the declaration itself:

```
template<typename T, size_t n>
using arrayRef = T (&)[n];

for (arrayRef<int,4> p : ia) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You write a typedef the same way as you write a variable declaration, except that you replace the variable name with the name you want to give to the type, and you stick `typedef` in front, hence:

```
typedef int (&R)[4];
```

will declare `R` to be the type "reference to an array of 4 `int`s".

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.